# How to delete an empty directory (or the directory with all contents recursively) in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I can't figure out how to delete all contents of a directory.

For cleaning out a directory, I want to remove all files and directories inside it: I want to wipe everything there is inside (files and directories).

I tried this with the delete task, but I can't figure out to make it also remove directories and not just files. I've tried different ways to specify the directories, but nothing works.

```
task deleteGraphicsAssets(type:Delete) {
    delete fileTree('src').include('**/*')
}
```

.

```
task deleteGraphicsAssets(type:Delete) {
    delete fileTree('src').include('/')
}
```

.

```
task deleteGraphicsAssets(type:Delete) {
    delete fileTree('src').include('*')
}
```

Any help appreciated!

---

Edit:

This works - yet it seems a bit like a hack.

```
task deleteGraphicsAssets(type: Delete) {
    def dirName = "src"
    delete dirName

    doLast {
        file(dirName).mkdirs()
    }
}
```

I was looking for something like:

```
task deleteGraphicsAssets(type: Delete) {
    deleteContentsOfDirectory "src"
}
```

or

```
task deleteGraphicsAssets(type: Delete) {
    delete {dir : "src", keepRoot : true }
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To delete the `src` directory and all its contents:

```
task deleteGraphicsAssets(type: Delete) {
    delete "src"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't do exactly what I asked for buy I can create a new one after the deletion. The only thing is that it seems a bit of hack... (See edit above for the whole solution).

Comment: I don't think it's possible to keep `src` itself around (when using `Delete`). Without knowing the specifics of your situation, I'd generally say that (re)creating `src` shouldn't be the responsibility of the `delete` task, but the responsibility of whatever tasks need the (empty) `src` directory to be present. Note that many Gradle tasks will automatically create parent directories if necessary.

Comment: Ok, seems like to me that both are valid ways to think about it. Thanks for pointing out the way this is usually done in gradle. My way of thinking was just that there's a container and a task puts things into that container. That the container is not created by that task but instead that the container always there. It's probably easier to think of the task creating an "object" which IS the directory and its contents.

Answer (score 14):

At the risk of resurrecting an answered topic, there's a relatively easy way to do this.

This task will delete all files and directories under 'src' without traversing the file tree and without removing to 'src' dir

```
task deleteGraphicsAssets(type:Delete) {
    delete file('src').listFiles()
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Groovy enhances the File class with several methods. You can delete a directory with all it's subdirectories and files using deleteDir() method.

```
task deletebin << {
    def binDir = new File('bin')
    binDir.deleteDir()
}
```

Comment: Did you see the answer from @peter-niederwieser above? That seems to do the same thing as yours but with a bit less code.

Comment: Is someone having a bad day?

Comment: @treesAreEverywhere Peter's code is an extension of the `delete` task, which merely _configures_ what _will_ be deleted.  If you need the delete to happen immediately (e.g. as a step in a larger task/process), then this answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

Following will delete all content from the src folder but leaves the folder itself untouched:

```
task deleteGraphicsAssets(type: Delete) {
    def dirName = "src" 
    file( dirName ).list().each{
        f -> 
            delete "${dirName}/${f}"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a much faster solution for deep trees than @DuncanSungWKim's answer. You can also just use `listFiles()` and then `delete f`

Comment: HOLY SH** I've tried everything, only this one worked for me! thx!!

Answer (score 4):

```
clean {
    delete += fileTree('src').include('**/*')
}
```

This 'clean' task's configuration seems to work.

Comment: FWIW,  `clean { delete += "src" }` gets rid of everything, including the directory.  the method mentioned above leaves the `src` there.

Comment: This removes all files but leaves empty subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Found using [FileTree#visit](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileTree.html#visit(org.gradle.api.file.FileVisitor)) worked.

```
ConfigurableFileTree ft = fileTree('someDir')
ft.include("xxx")
ft.exclude("yyy")

task delteFilesOnly() {
    doLast {
        //// for test
        //ft.each { File file ->
        //    println "===== " + file.absolutePath
        //}
        delete ft
    }
}

task deleteFilesAndDirs(){
    doLast {
        ft.visit { FileVisitDetails fvd ->
            //// for test
            //println "----- " + file.absolutePath
            delete fvd.file
        }
    }
}
```