# Deleting directories via gradle FileTree.include

Tags: gradle

I want to say:

```
clean.delete(fileTree("a") {
   include "subdir/"
   include "aFile"
})
```

to delete the directory "subdir" and the file "aFile".  But "subdir" is not deleted.  I could list it explicitly:

```
clean.delete("a/subdir")
```

but that is more repetitious than I would like.  Can fileTree.include be made to do this job?

So far I have come up with:

```
[ "subdir",
  "aFile",
  ...
].each { it -> 
   clean.delete("a/$it") 
}
```

but that is just a bit awkward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am afraid this is not possible. See this [discussion](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_do_i_delete_a_subset_of_files) on the gradle forum. The discussion lead to this [issue](http://issues.gradle.org//browse/GRADLE-2822).

A simple test shows

```
task makeDir << {
    ['a', 'a/subdir'].each { new File(it).mkdirs() }
    new File('a/aFile').createNewFile()

    def tree = fileTree('a') {
        include 'subdir/'
        include 'aFile'
    }

    tree.each {File file ->
        println file
    }
}
```

prints only the file and not the directory, as the directory is traversed. Your solution is good but you could save some chars:

```
[ "subdir",
  "aFile",
  ...
].each { clean.delete("a/$it") }
```

So fileTree is just for files in a directory tree and not for directories.

Comment: Thanks for a definitive answer, and a reasonable suggestion (I had already gone there pretty messy).  Nice to know I'm not the only one who has faced this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify it this way:

```
clean {
   delete 'a/aFile', 'a/subdir'
}
```

No idea why `fileTree` doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid repeating the parent ("a") for each entry.

Comment: I suppose it's possible but currently have now idea how it can be done.

Comment: Maybe this post will also help You somehow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299455/how-to-delete-an-empty-directory-or-the-directory-with-all-contents-recursively

Answer (score 0):

How about this way?

```
clean.delete(file('a').listFiles().findAll { it.getName() == 'subdir' || it.getName() == 'aFile' })
```

I just happened to figure out how to delete all directories and files under my build directory with exclusion of one specific directory.

```
clean.delete(file('build').listFiles().findAll { it.getName() != 'tools' })
```