# Delete subdirectory excluding files in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a directory, lets say `DirA`. There is a subdirectory called `DirB` and some files in `DirA`. Now, when I use the Gradle task to delete only the subdirectory (`DirB`), it is deleting the files also. I don't want it to delete the files. Can anyone please help me achieve this?

```
task deleteFolder(type: Delete){
   delete "full path of subdirectory relative to build.gradle location"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following structure:

```
.
└── dira
    ├── a
    ├── b
    ├── c
    └── dirb
```

and script:

```
task clearDirA(type: Delete) {
    delete project.file('dira/dirb')
}
```

Comment: I actually want to delete only DirB and not DirA or the files.

Comment: @Van it's not possible with `fileTree`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274966/deleting-directories-via-gradle-filetree-include

Comment: So, is it possible to achieve this with your code or not?

Comment: @Ven edited answer works just fine in all cases. If `dirb` is empty it won't work with `fileTree`. Haven't you tested it?

Comment: @Ven is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't get a chance to try it yet. Please give me sometime.