# Gradle task to delete contents in a directory but exclude jar file

Tags: gradle

I still trying to learn Gradle Task authoring.

I found the following solution to help with deleting the contents of a directory while leaving the directory untouched.

However can I please have help modifying it to exclude specific files such as the .jar file?

[How to delete an empty directory (or the directory with all contents recursively) in gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299455/how-to-delete-an-empty-directory-or-the-directory-with-all-contents-recursively)

The solution was given by Heri

```
task deleteGraphicsAssets(type: Delete) {
    def dirName = "src" 
        file( dirName ).list().each{
        f -> delete "${dirName}/${f}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
task deleteGraphicsAssets(type: Delete) {
    doLast {
        file('src').eachFileRecurse(groovy.io.FileType.FILES) { File file ->
            //Delete all files except *.jar
            if (!file.name.endsWith('.jar')) {
                delete file
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Another option, is using [Filetree](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:file_trees) for more advanced filter, for example:

```
task deleteGraphicsAssets(type: Delete) {
    delete fileTree(dir: "tempDir", exclude: "dontDelete.jar")
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I tried what you have and it gave me an error.   " > No signature of method: build_bl71j7zy0i2thp4z81o926i3g$_run_closure9$_closure16.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [.DS_Store]
  Possible solutions: doCall(java.io.File), findAll(), findAll(), isCase(java.lang.Object), isCase(java.lang.Object)"